# MySQL query that works but extremely slow

Tags: mysql, join

I have a developer who has created a query joining 3 tables in a method that I have never seen before.  This query is working although extremely slow.  I am trying to understand how this query is functioning because it seems to be extremely poorly designed.  I have tried to create a working sample that will hopefully clearly show the issue.

```
SELECT A.Col1, C.Col3
    FROM TABLEA A 
        INNER JOIN TABLEB B
            ON A.... = B....
        LEFT JOIN TABLEC C
            ON A.... = C....  AND A.... = C....
                AND B... = C.... AND B... = C.... AND B... = C... AND B... = C....
```

Notice how on the LEFT JOIN they have pulled in conditions from both TABLE A and TABLE B to join to C.  Is this creating some sort of derived or temporary table in the background?

Comment: Please include the output of [`EXPLAIN EXTENDED`](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/06/15/explain-extended-can-tell-you-all-kinds-of-interesting-things/) (see also [here](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/mysql/getting-an-execution-plan) for the query in question. Also, please give the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE A\G` (and for tables B and C). Also, please use the formatting widgets at the top of the text box where you ask or edit (you can always edit) your own questions.

Comment: Do you have indexes (B....), (C...., C....)?